# How to redefine the scroll in a listview

Tags: android

I have a listview with headers as you can see here : http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/

I would like to redefine the scroll behavior, to always let the current header on the top of the list. So if I have 20 items under my header, the listview scrolls on these items, keeping the header on screen, and then, the next header comes and takes the place of the previous one.

Is there a method to do that ?

Comment: I don't see any built in way to do that, but you could have a textview on top of your list, an update its content based on a property of your rows. This way, you could even get rid off your headers...?

Comment: Hmm, I think that the headers are important to see what is comming, when the user scrolls down.  But your solution could be an interesting alternative. When an header item disappears during the scrolling down, I update the content of the textview on top of the list.  

But it's going to be heavy to implement, and not really sexy. I hoped that a built in solution was already developped...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this library matches your requirement: https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders

Comment: Well, since 2010 I found the solution, and forgot to post here. But this lib seems to be easy to use and probably do the job well, so I'll accept this answer.